# AudioMetaTagger: recursively read files and gather metadata

Tags: java, performance, recursion, audio

So the idea is to read metadata recursively in a chosen directory, load their metadata and display it into a table.

Here is the simplified example of what I am doing.

```
public class AudioMetadataExtractorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String audioFiles = "C:\\Music";

       File dir = new File(audioFiles);
       Collection col = checkData(dir);

       for(Object object : col){
        File fil = (File) object;
        System.out.println(fil.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            printMetaData(fil);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
       System.out.println(col.size());
   }
```

In this case I am using the apachi.commons library to gather all files.

```
    public static Collection checkData(File dir){
    Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(
              dir, 
              new RegexFileFilter("^(.*mp3)"), 
              DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY
            );
    return files;
}
```

And with jaudiotagger read and print the metadata.

```
    public static void printMetaData(File file) throws Exception {
    AudioFile audioFile = null;
    audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(file);
    Tag tag = audioFile.getTag();
    for (FieldKey key : FieldKey.values()) {
        if(key==FieldKey.ALBUM){
        System.out.println(key + " " + tag.getFirst(key));
        }
    }
}
```

While this code works, it is extremely slow. I am confident there is a more efficient way of doing this.

- Is it bad practice to loop over objects and cast them within the loop?
- Is the jaudiotagger library an intrinsically slow library?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to code review! Here are some thoughts:

**Casting**

To get rid of the casting you can use generics (see also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) like so:

```
public static Collection<File> checkData(File dir){
    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(
        dir, 
        new RegexFileFilter("^(.*mp3)"), 
            DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY
        );
    return files;
}
```

This way in your main function you can avoid the casting:

```
 Collection<File> files = checkData(dir);
 for(File file: files) {
```

This is to be preferred, as casting is to be avoided when possible (Interesting related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167304/why-should-casting-be-avoided).

**Code**

Why initialize a variable first and then assign the value? You can easily do it in one line, which is nicer to read:

```
AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(file);
```

**Formatting**

On the nitpicky side, you should take a look at how code formatting is usually done in java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Using decent indentation and spacing allows for easier reading of the code. The best advice here is probably using the auto-formatter of your IDE (eclipse, intelliJ, etc.), as it is tedious to do it by hand.

**Performance**

Judging from your code, I don't see any specific place to make it a lot faster using the library. It looks like the library reads the entire file to get the metaData, which is of course very I/O intense, and therefor slow. 
More advanced libraries like JAudioTagger (http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_read.jsp) might be able to do this in a more efficient way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the well documented answer. (+1) I will take a look at the casting reference for a deeper understanding of it. As for the formatting I must practice that habit to notice the subtle differences.

Comment: @Scavence I had another look at some libraries for extracting meta data from audio files and found this one: http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_read.jsp Looks like it could do what you need (haven't tested it though).

Comment: `tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE)` works more code efficient and spares me the loop, which is always good. But unfortunately performance-wise still (quite) the same.

Answer (score 1):

A few minor things in addition to [@Nihathrael](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/57955/nihathrael)'s good points.

---

This loop is pointless:

> ```
> for (FieldKey key : FieldKey.values()) {
>     if(key==FieldKey.ALBUM){
>     System.out.println(key + " " + tag.getFirst(key));
>     }
> }
> ```

This is exactly the same but simpler, and without unnecessary looping:

```
FieldKey key = FieldKey.ALBUM;
System.out.println(key + " " + tag.getFirst(key));
```

---

In this code:

> ```
> Collection col = checkData(dir);
> ```

Both the variable name and the method are poorly named. This would be better:

```
Collection<File> mp3Files = findMp3Files(dir);
```

Especially as your code gets longer, good names will help a lot with readability.

---

You catch generic `Exception` and declare to throw generic `Exception` in many places.
Use the most specific exception type possible.
This can make your code less buggy by not catching unintentionally a type of `Exception` that you didn't expect to happen.
It also makes the code more readable,
as the reviewer can see what can possibly go wrong.

Comment: _This loop is pointless:_ Figured the tag.getfirst() method was more appropriate, but thanks for pointing that out. About the exceptions: multicatch when needed, use a logger, and throw user-relevant exceptions to main frame to be revealed to the user is sufficient? 

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/04/java-exception-handling-best-practices/

Comment: That's a pretty nice article. If you follow everything in there, that should be pretty good!

Answer (score 1):

Re `checkData(...)`: I find Java 7+'s [java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html) described in [The Java™ Tutorials, Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) extremely helpful. Thus avoiding a dependency to an extra library, Apache Commons, as long as no other things of it are used anyway.